# can we connect Laravel Routing Parameter and Controller Parameter?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

So I want to fill key but it fill another parameter when inside controller and i see it will fill the first parameter first.
Is There Anyway to make key? will go to $key parameter and type? to $type and fill? to $fill too ?

I'm Using Laravel 5.6.*

```
Route::get('/report', 'ReportAPIController@index')->name('api.report');
Route::get('/report/all', 'ReportAPIController@all')->name('api.report.all');
Route::get('/report/all/key/{key?}', 'ReportAPIController@all')->name('api.report.all.key');
Route::get('/report/all/search/{type?}/{fill?}', 'ReportAPIController@all')->name('api.report.all.type.fill');
Route::get('/report/all/search/{type?}/{fill?}/key/{key?}', 'ReportAPIController@all')->name('api.report.all.type.fill.key');
```

expected result : null null testing
/report/all/key/testing

```
public function all($type = null,$fill = null,$key = null)
{
    dd($type.$fill.$key); 
}
```

actual result : testing null null
/report/all/key/testing

```
public function all($type = null,$fill = null,$key = null)
{
    dd($type.$fill.$key); 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could replace the parameters inside `all()` and type-hint `Illuminate\Http\Request` instead.

Then, you could just do this:

```php
use Illuminate\Http\Request; 

public function all(Request $request)
{
    $key  = $request->key;
    $type = $request->type;
    $fill = $request->fill;

    dd($type.$fill.$key); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, it works like a charm. I was going to make Function for each route :D

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a route, Laravel goes through your list of routes top to bottom, until it finds one that 'matches' at which point this route is immediately selected.
So, 
`Route::get('/report/{id}',...` 
and 
`Route::get('/report/all,...`

for request kind of `/report/all` will match the `/report/{id}`, because it's the first MATCH.

In your case, you have to revert your routes order, so hardest to achieve routes will be first.

Comment: OP doesn't have a route `report/{id}` though.

Comment: I know, it was just for better understanding of problem.